# Conditional aggregate on existing query

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I have following table structure (I'm using MySQL 8):

```sql
CREATE TABLE `listings` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `types` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `county` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `state` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `zip` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `latitude` decimal(10,8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `longitude` decimal(11,8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` decimal(12,2) NOT NULL,
  `price_per_acre` decimal(12,2) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((`price` / `area`)) STORED,
  `area` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `local_avg_price_per_acre` decimal(12,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `local_median_price_per_acre` decimal(12,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `local_min_price_per_acre` decimal(12,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price_to_local_ratio` decimal(8,4) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((`price_per_acre` / `local_avg_price_per_acre`)) STORED,
  `notes` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `status` smallint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `checked_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `listings_state_county_area_index` (`state`,`county`,`area`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

The table is populated with the data except following fields `local_avg_price_per_acre`, `local_median_price_per_acre`, `local_min_price_per_acre` and I need to calculate them to do the update query with calculated values. By local here I mean more or less similar listings and similars for this project are those (who are in the same state and county and have +/-50% area of the listing that I'm doing calculation for)
For calculating `local_avg_price_per_acre` I have come up with the following query:

```sql
SELECT
    `t1`.`id`,
    (SUM(`t2`.`price`) / SUM(`t2`.`area`)) AS `avg`
FROM
    `listings` AS `t1`
    JOIN (
        SELECT
            `j1`.`id`,
            `j1`.`price`,
            `j1`.`area`,
            `j1`.`price_per_acre`,
            `j1`.`county`,
            `j1`.`state`
        FROM
            `listings` AS `j1`
        WHERE
            `j1`.`status` IN (1, 2)
    ) AS `t2` ON `t2`.`area` BETWEEN `t1`.`area` * 0.5 AND `t1`.`area` * 1.5
    AND `t1`.`county` = `t2`.`county`
    AND `t1`.`state` = `t2`.`state`
WHERE
    `t1`.`status` IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY
    `t1`.`id`
HAVING
    COUNT(`t2`.`id`) > 8
ORDER BY
    `t1`.`id`
LIMIT
    100 OFFSET 0;
```

and the output for `EXPLAIN`:

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | t1 | NULL | index | PRIMARY,listings_state_county_area | PRIMARY | 8 | NULL | 795479 | 20.00 | Using where |
| 1 | SIMPLE | j1 | NULL | ref | listings_state_county_area | listings_state_county_area | 2044 | cheaplandsearch.t1.state,cheaplandsearch.t1.county | 188 | 2.22 | Using index condition; Using where |

Now I need to also add `MIN` calculation but with added condition, that those accounting for min will be from the same set, but their `price_per_acre` will be in average +/- 2 * standard deviation, so I thought to do something like:

```sql
SELECT
    `t1`.`id`,
    (SUM(`t2`.`price`) / SUM(`t2`.`area`)) AS `avg`,
    STDDEV_SAMP(`t2`.`price_per_acre`) AS `stddev`
FROM
    `listings` AS `t1`
    JOIN (
        SELECT
            `j1`.`id`,
            `j1`.`price`,
            `j1`.`area`,
            `j1`.`price_per_acre`,
            `j1`.`county`,
            `j1`.`state`
        FROM
            `listings` AS `j1`
        WHERE
            `j1`.`status` IN (1, 2)
    ) AS `t2` ON `t2`.`area` BETWEEN `t1`.`area` * 0.5 AND `t1`.`area` * 1.5
    AND `t1`.`county` = `t2`.`county`
    AND `t1`.`state` = `t2`.`state`
    JOIN (
        SELECT
            `j2`.`id`,
            `j2`.`price_per_acre`
        FROM
            `listings` AS `j2`
    ) AS `t3` ON `t3`.`id` = `t2`.`id`
    AND `t3`.`price_per_acre` >= (`avg` - 2 * `stddev`)
    AND `t3`.`price_per_acre` <= (`avg` + 2 * `stddev`)
WHERE
    `t1`.`status` IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY
    `t1`.`id`
HAVING
    COUNT(`t2`.`id`) > 8
ORDER BY
    `t1`.`id`
LIMIT
    100 OFFSET 0;
```

But the added conditions (for `price_per_acre`) for second join don't work, I get error `Unknown column 'avg' in 'on clause'`. As I understand `avg` and `stddev` are not available by the time of join yet. The only way currently to add conditional MIN I got is (wrapped the original one in subquery, did another join with added conditions):

```sql
SELECT
    `o1`.`id`,
    `o2`.`avg`,
    `o2`.`stddev`,
    MIN(`o3`.`price_per_acre`) AS `min`
FROM
    `listings` AS `o1`
    JOIN (
        SELECT
            `t1`.`id`,
            (SUM(`t2`.`price`) / SUM(`t2`.`area`)) AS `avg`,
            STDDEV_SAMP(`t2`.`price_per_acre`) AS `stddev`
        FROM
            `listings` AS `t1` 
            JOIN (
                SELECT
                    `j1`.`id`,
                    `j1`.`price`,
                    `j1`.`area`,
                    `j1`.`price_per_acre`,
                    `j1`.`county`,
                    `j1`.`state`
                FROM
                    `listings` AS `j1`
                WHERE
                    `j1`.`status` IN (1, 2)
            ) AS `t2` ON `t2`.`area` >= `t1`.`area` * 0.5
            AND `t2`.`area` <= `t1`.`area` * 1.5
            AND `t1`.`county` = `t2`.`county`
            AND `t1`.`state` = `t2`.`state`
        WHERE
            `t1`.`status` IN (1, 2)
        GROUP BY
            `t1`.`id`
        HAVING
            COUNT(`t2`.`id`) > 8
        ORDER BY
            `t1`.`id`
        LIMIT
            100 OFFSET 0
    ) AS `o2` ON `o1`.`id` = `o2`.`id`
    JOIN (
        SELECT
            `j2`.`id`,
            `j2`.`price`,
            `j2`.`area`,
            `j2`.`price_per_acre`,
            `j2`.`county`,
            `j2`.`state`
        FROM
            `listings` AS `j2`
        WHERE
            `j2`.`status` IN (1, 2)
    ) AS `o3` ON `o3`.`area` >= `o1`.`area` * 0.5
    AND `o3`.`area` <= `o1`.`area` * 1.5
    AND `o3`.`county` = `o1`.`county`
    AND `o3`.`state` = `o1`.`state`
    AND `o3`.`price_per_acre` >= (`avg` - 2 * `stddev`)
    AND `o3`.`price_per_acre` <= (`avg` + 2 * `stddev`);
```

and the output for `EXPLAIN`:

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY | derived2 | NULL | ALL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 100 | 100.00 | Using temporary |
| 1 | PRIMARY | o1 | NULL | eq_ref | PRIMARY,listings_state_county_area | PRIMARY | 8 | o2.id | 1 | 100.00 | NULL |
| 1 | PRIMARY | j2 | NULL | ref | listings_state_county_area | listings_state_county_area | 2044 | cheaplandsearch.o1.state,cheaplandsearch.o1.county | 188 | 0.25 | Using index condition; Using where |
| 2 | DERIVED | t1 | NULL | index | PRIMARY,listings_state_county_area | PRIMARY | 8 | NULL | 795479 | 20.00 | Using where |
| 2 | DERIVED | j1 | NULL | ref | listings_state_county_area | listings_state_county_area | 2044 | cheaplandsearch.t1.state,cheaplandsearch.t1.county | 188 | 2.22 | Using index condition; Using where |

As you see from `EXPLAIN` output it already becomes very heavy query with derived temporary table, which I'm not sure is the most optimal way, but it still works more or less ok if it is the only way.

So the questions are:

1. Is there a way to calculate the minimum with better query than in my 3rd example
2. How can I add also median calculation there from the same joined table as `avg` (without additional conditions for minimum) like `MEDIAN(t2.price_per_acre)` in first query, but obviously mysql doesn't have `MEDIAN` aggregate function.

P.S. Here is [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=699d53e0235d5c17e35d46a2072518a9) with demo data if you want work with that.

Comment: @HannahVernon Thanks, I've replaced images with MD tables, though they don't have horizontal scrolling (not sure if it was possible).

Comment: that's awesome - thanks!  And they have scrollbars for me 

Comment: I don't see any reference to latitude or longitude; is "local" based only on "in the same county"?  (Lat/lng would add a lot of complexity.)

Comment: If you are eager for `MEDIAN()`, switch to MariaDB 10.3 or later.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of computing `avg` in the `SELECT`, compute it in a derived table.

Then move the use of `avg` outside of a derived table.

Something like

```
SELECT ...
    FROM ( SELECT ... AS avg
             ... ) AS x
    JOIN ...
    WHERE ... >= (x.avg - 2 * `stddev`)
```

You may need another level of nested Selects, I don't know.